# Interpreting a Partial Autocorrelation Function Plot

Tags: data-visualization, autocorrelation, autoregressive

[image: PACF Plot]

Here's the plot in question. The first two are obviously significant, but I am having trouble determining the next two. The third lag looks too small, but I am borderline on the fourth. Should I be using just two lags or four here?